# Merge two plots into one with logarithmic scale - different data frames pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, subplot

I would like to combine next two plots into one plot on a logarithmic scale.

```
df1.plot(x = 'Interval', y = 'Trend')
plt.yscale("log")
plt.show()

df2.plot(x = 'Value', y = 'Reliability')
plt.yscale("log")
plt.show()
```

How to merge these two plots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) you can pass in the axes you want to plot to. Therefore, your code would become:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df1.plot(x = 'Interval', y = 'Trend', ax=ax)
df2.plot(x = 'Value', y = 'Reliability', ax=ax)

ax.set_yscale("log")
plt.show()
```